# Why does my girlfriend get sleepy during exercise?

Tags: exercise, sleep

My girlfriend gets very sleepy while exercising and yawns all the time. We have searched online but couldn't find any answers except a few brief mentions of several possibilities, like heart or blood pressure problems (she has very mild anaemia), sleep depravation (not at all, she sleeps **a lot** - she can sleep 11 hours during the night and still take a nap in the afternoon) or fatigue (also not the case, on the contrary, she has been having a very sedentary life lately, unfortunately).

Any ideas on what could be the cause for this sleepiness that strikes her just a few minutes after she starts exercising?

Comment: Hey! Sorry, but this site probably isn't the best place to get an answer to your question, since it looks like you're asking for a list of possible diagnoses for a symptom. That's not really this site's specialty.

Comment: Hi @borfast! Welcome to the site. The question sounds like you would be better to talk to a medical professional. You haven't provided any details about your girlfriend, and all we'd be doing is playing a guessing game. I'm not really sure what you'd expect in the end given that. I'm closing this question which does not fit well with this site. You are welcome, however, to ask other questions related to fitness or exercise. Please have a look at our [faq] to get a better idea of topics are in scope for this site.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a diagnosis, I know this is not a medical clinic. I was merely wondering if anyone else had experienced or knew someone who felt the same symptoms, and if they would be able to point us in the right direction. It's something related to exercise and if someone here knows something about it that may shed some light on the subject - both for me and future readers - why is it not constructive?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help but feel this - and a bunch of other questions I've seen closed on StackExchange sites for "not being constructive" - is a bit ridiculous. People close other people's questions without even trying to understand the question or thinking about it for a bit. I love stackexchange but it could be so much more if it wasn't for this "shoot first, ask questions later" attitude...

Comment: @borfast - Given that the reason for yawns themselves is still not really understood, and there are myriad reasons that she could be getting sleepy ranging from not breathing enough to nutrition to being sick to...well, you get the idea. We love helping, but this would be nothing more than throwing darts at a board and hoping something sticks. I would really recommend talking to a medical professional if it is something you are concerned about.

Comment: @borfast StackExchange is great because it has rules and users that stick to them. Read [Let’s Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) why these kind of questions are considered not constructive.

Comment: If you want to discuss this further you should open a question on [meta].